# Manual VS Automatic Array Clarification

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsarray, nsfilemanager

In my app, I'm going from creating an array of objects manually to creating an equal array where the objects are stored in a reference folder. I create the automatic array with contentsOfDirectoryAtPath.

The problem is  when I reference the array later in my collection view, cellForItemAtIndexPath. The manually created array runs fine but the automatic array is not in the same format and throws an ERROR.

The difference is the manually created array has 3 objects and the automatically created array has one object, shown in the log by the extra set of parenthesis. How may I get the automatically created array to add each folder object individually so I can get an array with 3 objects just like I did with the manually created array? Thanks in advance for your time.

Manually create targetArray

```
//@interface

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *targetArray;

//viewdidLoad   

self.targetArray = @[@"one",@"two", @"three"];

NSLog(@"Target Array description test = %@", [_targetArray description]);

//returns

Target Array description test = (
"one",
"two",
"three"
 )
```

Automatically create array by reading reference folder

```
//@interface

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *targetArray;

//viewdidLoad

for (int i = 0; i <= [folderArray count] -1; i++) {

NSString *sectionString = [folderArray objectAtIndex:i];

NSMutableArray *subFolderArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSArray *targetArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:folderPath error:nil];

NSLog(@"Target Array description test = %@", [_targetArray description]);

}

//returns

Target Array description test = (
    (
    "one",
    "two",
    "three"
  )
 )
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath for w/Error log for reference

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

sheetCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"SheetCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSLog(@"Target Array description test = %@", [_targetArray description]);

NSString *sheetString = [self.targetArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

ERROR: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM stringByDeletingPathExtension]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78794450'

cell.sheetImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:sheetString];

cell.sheetLabel.text = sheetString;

return cell;

}
```

Comment: You seem to have two different objects entitled targetArray: one is self.targetArray (also accessed by its instance variable _targetArray) and another which you declare in the for loop (NSArray *targetArray).  Your NSLogs only refer to the former.  Also your for loop has no closing } - is that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

If you know that "contentsOfDirectoryAtPath" method will always return an array of objects with in a single element outer array, you could "unpackage" the inner array by:

```
NSArray *targetArray = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:folderPath error:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

(I'm not at my computer to run the above through XCode to check it compiles)

As a side note, there was a fews issues with the code snippets you provided (could be typos or copy/paste errors) in that you are assigning to a local variable called "targetArray" and then accessing an instance variable called "targetArray" in the print statement - not the same objects.